# How to use a custom debug.keystore in Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi

We often need to set `debug.keystore` fingerprint in libraries (like Facebook SDK or Firebase).

However, as I understand this file is unique and generated for each user and even for each version of Delphi. So for every Delphi update or new user in the team we need to log and update the fingerprint in every API we use.

Is there any way we can specify in project settings exact `debug.keystore` file we want to use (for debugging).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi does not have setting allowing you to specify location of `debug.keystore`.

It uses file located in `C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\19.0`

You have to manually copy file you want to use into that location (use appropriate version number - above path is for Delphi Tokyo). Also when upgrading from one version to another just copy existing file to location appropriate for new version.

Yo can also freely share same `debug.keystore` among internal developers using different computers.