# Error publishing Delphi 11 Android Application to the Google Play Store: "Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key."

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I  developed an Android application with RAD Studio 11, and generated the `.aab` file to import to the Google Play store.

When importing the `.aab` file, I have the following error:

> Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
>
> SHA1: (app key)
>
> but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has fingerprint:
>
> SHA1: (app key)

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are the both keys fingerprints the same? If not you need to find your signing key with the certificate fingerprint that matches the expected certificate key.

Comment: no the keys are not the same. Please, where to find  certificate fingerprint and how can i change it in rad studio?

Comment: Where have you saved your release keystore file? You need to use that file to sign the application. If you have stored that keystore in default location provided by Delphi, and you created it with previous Delphi version, it is probably in version specific folder. Take a look at (note that Q is about debug.keystore, but default folders are the same): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371098/how-to-use-a-custom-debug-keystore-in-delphi

Comment: I generated keystore file from rad stdio ide  project->option->Provisioning->new keystore. I introduced random file name "myfilename.keystore" and password "mypassword" for keystore. I have chosen a file location on my desktop.

Comment: You need to find that file and add it to your project in Project Options -> Provisioning -> Android - Application Store

Comment: I did that still not working

Comment: Are you sure that certificate on your Desktop is the one you have originally uploaded to Play Store console?

Comment: I checked the .keystore file using java keytool the sha1 is not the same as sha1 provided by google. Now, do you have any idea how can i change the sha1 of the .keystore file generated by the rad studio?  Thanks lot Dalija

Comment: You cannot change its fingerprint. That is the whole point of having certificate, so that only person with right certificate can update the application. If you cannot find or don't know where is the certificate that is uploaded on Play Store, and you are using [Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en) you can contact support and ask resetting your upload key. If you are not using Play App Signing, then you cannot upload without original certificate. If it is lost you can only create new application with new ID.

Comment: I am lost here! I created a new app in play store and new release with google-Generated key i didn't get any .keystore file only a .cer file. I looked to tutorial on the internet they are all dated only for app submitting before august. Do you know what to do from here?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352681/convert-cer-certificate-to-jks